# qml application not shown main window

Tags: qt, windows-10, qml

I have qml Windows application. 
When run it in debug mode, everything is ok.
When I make build and run it from C:\Program Files... directory, main window not shown.

There is two things, who shown that application works - after start.
Application need file on disk. If not exists, create it.

When application start, from C:\Program Files... it make a file. It show, that app work - after start.

In task manager exe is visible.

But there is no window visible after start...

Can you help me?

Comment: Your application probably missed needed files.  Use [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply... I used windeploy of course... Problem was in missing --qmldir argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use windeployqt with --qmldir. Read this manual http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html .